# Jetpack Compose: Can't do Modifier.animateItemPlacement() in LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to animate elements in a `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` using the `Modifier.animateItemPlacement()` modifier, but I get the error:

`"Cannot access 'LazyGridItemScopeImpl': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid'"`

My code:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemScopeImpl.animateItemPlacement

LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(150.dp),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(noteItems.value.size, key = { noteItems.value[it].id!! }) { item ->
        NoteItem(modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(), noteItems.value[item])
    }
}
```

There is no information on the Internet, I don’t know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried you code and all are working fine. This my dependencies.

```
    val navVersion = "2.6.0"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navVersion")

    val compose_version= "1.5.4"
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")

    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha10")

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
```

Can you please share your dependencies?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! With these dependencies everything worked. There is some confusion with dependencies in Compose